# NetUserChangePassword C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to change user password on my Windows 7 PC using C++.

But when I compile it gets error:

```
 undefined reference to 'NetUserChangePassword' 
 [Error] ld returned 1 exit status.`
```

How can I fix it?

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the MSDN page with the `NetUserChangePassword` function:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>

bool ChangeUserPassword(LPCWSTR OldPassword, LPCWSTR NewPassword)
{
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
    LPTSTR lp = new TCHAR[256];
    DWORD dw = 256;
    GetUserName(lp, &dw);
    nStatus = NetUserChangePassword(NULL, lp, OldPassword, NewPassword);
    delete[] lp;
    if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    LPCWSTR Old_P = L"C";
    LPCWSTR New_P = L"D";
    ChangeUserPassword(Old_P, New_P);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to link to the project the winapi32.dll in two ways

1. i tried to add using the project option
2. i tried to add following line

   ```
   HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary( L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\netapi32.dll ");
   ```

but i get always the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: ensure that the path to the Lib folder of your SDK installation is part of the library search pathes of your linker project settings

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements section of the MSDN topic you linked to states that you must link the `Netapi32.lib` library. That is the step that you have missed and explains the missing external error.

As to how to resolve the problem it is hard to say for sure. You are not using the MS compiler and so the `#pragma` approach won't work. Consult the docs for your compiler/linker to work out how to link this library.

It looks like you are using a GCC based compiler and so need to add `-lnetapi32` to the options.

Comment: this line doesn't link NetApi32.lib ?
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

Comment: Not in your compiler. Use -l to specify libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you unaccepted. This is surely the answer.

Comment: You cannot expect any more specific instructions. You did not tell us the compiler that you use. You need to pass that library to your linker. What did the documentation for your compiler say? Did you read it like I suggested?

Comment: i wrote but the answer was cancelled sorry

Comment: i use DevCpp v 5.4.2.

Comment: that was not part of the question that I answered. Did you read the docs?

Comment: Yes but i have to link to project Netapi32.dll ?

Comment: You have to pass netapi32.lib to the linker. That's it. Did you read the docs?

Comment: Docs doesn't help a lot

Comment: I guess you also need to learn a bit about how linking works because your knowledge is hazy.